# Setup PaddleOCR on M1 Mac or Docker

Tags: docker, ocr, apple-m1, paddleocr

I was wondering if anyone has a good guide to setup PaddleOCR on M1 Mac or Docker. I want to use PaddleOCR to read license plates. I’m open to any suggestions. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i try install paddleocr on M1 Mac. problem in installation paddle, python arm M1 not supported install paddle,  and then i try with install [python3.8 intel installer](https://www.python.org/downloads/macos/) success.
more information please read [paddle installation](https://www.paddlepaddle.org.cn/install/quick?docurl=/documentation/docs/zh/develop/install/pip/macos-pip.html)

btw you can try my docker https://hub.docker.com/r/alimustoofaa/paddleocr